# RENAME vs RENAMENX in Redis?

Tags: redis

What's the exact difference between `RENAME` vs `RENAMENX` in [redis](/questions/tagged/redis)?

Obviously, I looked through Redis [commands](http://redis.io/commands/) page but couldn't understand the difference properly.
It would be great if someone can explain it through an example.

Comment: I kinda doubt your reading was in any way thorough :) https://monosnap.com/file/raG8Doj8T53zi2lwEBIDXiJjBtj5Kx.png. `RENAME` will overwrite newkey. `RENAMENX` won't. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RENAMENX` (Rename if the new key does not exist), will throw an error in case of the new key (to be renamed to) exists.

```
Case1:
     - Key renamed to new key.

Case2 (Existing new key):
     - Error, new key exists.
```

The `RENAME` command as the documentation shows, will rename the key to the new key (to be renamed to) even if it exists, **forcing** a `DEL`.

```
Case1:
     - Key renamed to new key. 

Case2 (Existing new key):
     - New Key exists.
     - Delete New Key and its value.
     - Key renamed.
```